# Interdependencies between two lerna monorepos

Tags: node.js, npm, lerna, monorepo

I'm having two monorepos which I want to develop simultaneously. Here's the structure:

**Monorepo A**

```
package.json
lerna.json
packages/
   componentA1
   componentA2
```

**Monorepo B**

```
package.json
lerna.json
packages/
   componentB1
   componentB2
```

Here are the dependencies:

```
1) componentA2 depends on componentA1
2) componentB2 depends on componentA1
3) monorepoB depends on componentA2
```

I'm using

```
lerna exec -- npm link
```

Command on both monorepos. This makes everything fine within one monorepo.
Now I do regular

```
npm link componentA1 componentA2
```

within monorepoB following their dependency relation.

While this works for componentB2 it fails for componentB1. The problem appears to be that linking won't work if the linked component itself depends on some internal package.

If I do npm ls componentA2 in monorepoB I get

```
└── @monorepoA/componentA2@x.x.x  -> /Users/kbhit/Sources/xxx/ddl-admin/ddl-admin-sass/packages/sass invalid
```

But links to componentA1 are valid (but it does not have transitive dependencies).

How to solve this issue?

Comment: What is the output of `npm link` commands? Have you manually checked what links are being created. Which links are supposed to be created that aren't actually being created? What is your OS? Are links relative or absolute?

Comment: npm link produces valid links, no errors reported, linking every package from the packages directory to node global folder. They are all aviable to be linked in the other project but when I do npm ls on the one with transitive dependencies afterwards I get "invalid" tag on it. My OS i MacOS, links are absolute.